# PHP and MySQL Loop the same QueryString via GET

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I am trying to do eCommerce filtering on the category page. So far I can get it to work for one colour, but if the user checks more than one colour, I want it to search for the other colour too.

## URL

```
//current
category.php?colourChoice=White
//more than one
category.php?colourChoice=White&colourChoice=Ruby+Red
```

I realise I need some sort of form array or an explode?

## MYSQL

```
products
---
id      sku     price
1       p22     45.00
2       p33     65.00   
3       p44     70.00

colours
---
id      sku     name
1       p22     White
2       p33     Ruby Red    
3       p44     Black
```

## HTML

```
<form action="form.php" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colourChoice" value="White"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colourChoice" value="Black"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colourChoice" value="Ruby Red"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colourChoice" value="Orange"/>
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

## PHP

```
// VARS
$colourName=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["colourChoice"]);

// MYSQL
$checkSQL=mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM `products`
    INNER JOIN `colours`
    ON `products`.`sku` = `colours`.`sku`
    WHERE (
    name = '".$colourName."'
        OR name LIKE '".$colourName.";%'
        OR name LIKE '%;".$colourName.";%'
        OR name LIKE '%;".$colourName."'
    )
");

// SHOW RESULTS
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($checkSQL)) {
    echo '
        <div class="product">
            Cost £'.$r['price'].'<br />
        </div>
    ';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make **checkbox array** as below

```
<form action="form.php" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colourChoice[]" value="White"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colourChoice[]" value="Black"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colourChoice[]" value="Ruby Red"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colourChoice[]" value="Orange"/>
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Then, you will get multiple value checked into array in php.

```
foreach($_GET["colourChoice"] as $value){
  /// here you can make concat for where clause.
}
```

Comment: So here, $value would actually be equal to "White+Ruby+Red" how would it actually write the format what would $value actually look like.

Comment: It takes all the values that are actually checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can get HTML input values in PHP as array:

## HTML

```
<form action="form.php" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colourChoice[]" value="White"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colourChoice[]" value="Black"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colourChoice[]" value="Ruby Red"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colourChoice[]" value="Orange"/>
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Then you query the database using prepare/execute statements to prevent SQL injection.

## PHP

```
$placeholders = substr(str_repeat('?, ', count($_GET['colourChoice']), 0, -1);
$query = "
    SELECT * FROM `products`
    INNER JOIN `colours`
    ON `products`.`sku` = `colours`.`sku`
    WHERE name in ($placeholders);
");
$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($_GET['colourChoice']);
print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Comment: Wouldn't an `mysql_real_escape_string` work better here. There are 300-400 combinations of each set - and there is heavy traffic load.

Comment: Why would it be better? If there are so many checkboxes, keep also in mind that the query string is limited in length (mysql setting ```max_allowed_packet```). See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/1296402